# TypeError: b.lat is not a function - Heatmap Layer

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I'm stuck trying to figure out why I'm getting the above issue for my heat-layer. The answers I've seen on while seatching address improper LatLng setup, however my marker's LatLng array work just fine.

I've tried adding weights as well even though the api say it's optional.

```
var map;

function initMap(resultSet) {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps'), {
    center: {
        lat: 40.8173,
        lng: -96.7005
    },
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  });`

  var labels = [];
  var locations = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < resultSet.length; i++) {
    labels.push(resultSet[i][0]);
    locations.push({
        lat: parseFloat(resultSet[i][3]),
        lng: parseFloat(resultSet[i][4])
    });
    if (data[0] == '1') {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: locations[i],
            map: map,
            title: labels[i]
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
  }

  if (data[0] == '2') {
    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: locations,
    });
    heatmap.setMap(map);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`HeatmapLayer`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/visualization) is one of the remaining places you **can't** use a [`google.maps.LatLngLiteral`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngLiteral) for a position, it **must be** a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng) object.
(the error you get is because the anonymous object `LatLngLiteral` doesn't have a `.lat()` method, it has a `.lat` property).

Change:

```
for (var i = 0; i < resultSet.length; i++) {
    labels.push(resultSet[i][0]);
    locations.push({
        lat: parseFloat(resultSet[i][3]),
        lng: parseFloat(resultSet[i][4])
    });
    if (data[0] == '1') {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: locations[i],
            map: map,
            title: labels[i]
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
}
```

To:

```
for (var i = 0; i < resultSet.length; i++) {
    labels.push(resultSet[i][0]);
    locations.push(new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(resultSet[i][3]),
        parseFloat(resultSet[i][4])
    ));
    if (data[0] == '1') {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: locations[i],
            map: map,
            title: labels[i]
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
}
```